# Typescript merging styled component props with the parent ones

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a styled component that look like this:

```
interface BoxProps {
    color?: string;
    backgroundColor?: string;
    borderColor?: string;
  }

export const Box = styled.div<BoxProps>`
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  text-align: left;
  color: ${(props) => props.color};
  background-color: ${(props) => props.backgroundColor};
  border-color: ${(props) => props.borderColor};
`;
```

It's wrapped in another component:

```
export const Container: React.FC<ContainerProps> = ({
  variant,
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  const { color, backgroundColor, borderColor } = variantColor(variant);

  return (
    <div>
      <Box
        color={color}
        backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
        borderColor={borderColor}
        {...props}
      >
        {children}
      </Box>
      <p></p>
      // ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

If I add `StyledComponent<"div", any, BoxProps, never>` to `React.FC<ContainerProps>`:

```
React.FC<ContainerProps & StyledComponent<"div", any, BoxProps, never>>
```

spreading props will give me the following error:
`Rest types may only be created from object types`
I tried `React.HTMLAttributes<{}> & typeof Box.propTypes` and `React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>` without luck...

Is there a way to merge a styled-component props with the parent props?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`styled.div` just renders a `div` and it accepts any properties `div` would accept + your properties from `BoxProps`. You can get a type that described properties of a JSX element using `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElementYouNeed>` in this case `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>`, so props of `Box` would now be this plus `BoxProps`:

```
React.FC<ContainerProps & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & BoxProps>
```

If you are too lazy to write this, you could make a utility namespace in some file in your project:

```
declare namespace HTMLProps {
  type div = React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivProps>
  // Maybe define props for other html elements if you need
}
export default HTMLProps
```

Then import this and use

```
React.FC<ContainerProps & HTMLProps.div & BoxProps>
```

Answer (score 4):

Alex's answer is valid but in some cases it won't work. For instance I had this styled component:

```
export const CustomInput = styled.input.attrs({ type: 'text' })``;
```

using:

```
React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
// or
Omit<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>,'type'>
```

gives an error in the parent component.

for this to work you need:

```
Omit<React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'>, 'type'>
```

Comment: Super helpful, thank you! In my case, I needed to omit the `className` prop since I was assigning `styled.div.attrs({ className: "group" })` for use with Twin.Macro / Tailwind on a styled component.